# Flutter Firebase Analytics No Data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-analytics

So I have a Flutter app setup with Firebase and I can't figure out why no analytics show up in the Analytics tab.

[image]

I have all the needed dependencies in my pubspec.yaml..

```
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.6
  firebase_core: ^1.12.0
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.6
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.0.1
  flutter_colorpicker: ^0.5.0
  flutter_hooks: ^0.18.0
  flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.2.0
  firebase_remote_config: ^1.0.2
  firebase_analytics: ^9.1.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.5.1
```

Here is my current build.gradle android level.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my current build.gradle app level.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mypackage.name"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'
}
```

Everything else I use in Firebase seems to log events fine (firestore, storage, etc). I've tried messing with the dependencies in the build.gradle files in the Android project but no luck there. Made sure my google-services.json was up to date. Any idea what I've done wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I think it might have just started working after adding the " implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'" in the build.gradle

Comment: Hello, did you check event logging in debug view? If not please follow https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

Comment: I have the same issue that 1 of my project is not able to send data to Firebase. But my another project, even I don't have "implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'", it still works. So I wonder there is another error on the setup. I have already included 'com.google.gms.google-services' in the setup.

Answer (score 2):

My issue is I am upgrading my flutter app to have latest Firebase plugin using the OLD firebase project.

I solve my issue by creaet a new firebase project in the firebase console and use:

```
flutterfire configure
```

to connect my flutter app to the new firebase project.

Than it works.

Notes: Preverious I have already checked the installation of google services, and also set allow debug view using adb shell. But turn out it doesn't not work  even I did all the checking.

Hope this could help if you are facing the same issue.